# Object Required when trying to label y axis

Tags: vba, runtime

I am trying to use Excel Macros for the first time, but for some reason the corresponding VBA code doesn't like it when I try to label the y axis. I get a run time error 424, and then it says object required.

```
Sub Graphplotz()
'
' Graphplotz Macro
'

'

    Range("A2:B15").Select
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(240, xlXYScatterSmooth).Select
    ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("Plot!$A$2:$B$15")
    ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Select
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = _
        "Stress vs. Deformation"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 22).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 6).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(7, 16).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 14
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Spacing = 0
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Deformation"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)
    ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Text = "Stress(Mpa)"
    Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters.Text = "Stress(Mpa)"
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).ParagraphFormat
        .TextDirection = msoTextDirectionLeftToRight
        .Alignment = msoAlignCenter
    End With
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Characters(1, 11).Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Bold = msoFalse
        .NameComplexScript = "+mn-cs"
        .NameFarEast = "+mn-ea"
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        .Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(89, 89, 89)
        .Fill.Transparency = 0
        .Fill.Solid
        .Size = 10
        .Italic = msoFalse
        .Kerning = 12
        .Name = "+mn-lt"
        .UnderlineStyle = msoNoUnderline
        .Strike = msoNoStrike
    End With
    Range("L7").Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Please remove everything from your code that isn't relevant to the problem. And point out the line that causes the error. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Replace
    ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis)

with

ActiveChart.SetElement msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleBelowAxis

The msoElementPrimaryValueAxisTitleAdjacentToAxis const does not appear to work.